# Return a string in boolean method

Tags: java, string, boolean

I have a boolean method as following below

```
public boolean validID(String personalNumber) { .... }
```

I wanna to print out a string "is valid" or "is not valid" dependent on if the boolean true or false.

the problem is how can I print out string in a boolean method. The code below return always false even if the if statment is true.

```
 if (sum % 10 == 0) {
        return Boolean.parseBoolean("is valid");
    } else {
        return false;
    }
```

Comment: You cannot. Instead use the call to this boolean-returning method in another place, and print there whether it is valid or not depending on the result (`true` or `false`)

Comment: It looks like your first return statement should just be `return true`.

Comment: Your method returns `boolean`. If you want to return a string first change its return type.

Comment: You're confusing *returning* and *printing*. Returning a value allows any caller to do whatever it wants with the returned value. One caller could use the boolean result to print a message "valid" or "invalid". Another caller could use it to start a process. A third one could use it to display a graphical notification. The point is: it's the **caller** which will use the returned boolean to do whatever it wants. Call the method, then test if it returns true, and if it is, print a message. Don't print or return a message from this method.

Comment: Do you want to print or return? Your question is confusing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have only two choices :

- a `boolean` method :

  ```
  public boolean validID(String personalNumber) { 
      // ... code to compute 'sum'
      return sum % 10 == 0;
  }
  ```
- a `String` method :

  ```
  public String validID(String personalNumber) { 
      // ... code to compute 'sum'
      if (sum % 10 == 0) {
          return personalNumber + " is valid";
      } else {
          return personalNumber + " is not valid";
      }
  }
  ```

Or a choice that combine both, the `String` one that calls the `boolean` one :

```
public boolean isValidId(String personalNumber) { 
    // ... code to compute 'sum'
    return sum % 10 == 0;
}

public String validID(String personalNumber) { 
    if (isValidId(personalNumber)) {
        return personalNumber + " is valid";
    } else {
        return personalNumber + " is not valid";
    }
}
```

I'd suggest to take the `boolean` one, the better is to let the method find the validity of the `personalNumber` and let the code that calls it handle the result to print a message, because you may this method again and this time you'll need the boolean result to handle it differently

```
String id = "fs6d7f6sd";
if(this.validID(id))
    System.out.println("ID is valid");
else
    System.out.println("ID is not valid");
```

Comment: There is a third choice, the first method in your answer calling the second one.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend to use bean `Result`.
Check my code.

```java
class Result {
    private boolean value;
    private String message;

    public Result(boolean value, String message) {
        this.value = value;
        this.message = message; 
    }
    // getter & setter
}

public Result validID(String number) { 
    // ... code to compute 'sum'
    return sum % 10 == 0 ? 
        new Result(true, "valid") : 
        new Result(false, "invalid");
}
```